# How to turn off flash protection against long executing scripts?

Tags: profiling, flash

I am profiling some AS code by measuring wall clock time. In order to minimize the error I need to run the code for a long period of time. However, flash seems to protect itself from unresponsive scripts by throwing an exception after some period of unresponsiveness, namely: `Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.`

Is there any way to disable this protection, or at least extend the timeout period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are publishing with Adobe Flash CS/4/5 etc.

Goto the publish settings. select "flash" at the bottom of this screen there is a textbox which says "Script Timeout" I know you can increase this, I think the limit is 90seconds even though you can enter any value here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you move execution of the script across separate frames, and add a timer to advance the frame before the timeout period has lapsed? I believe the error only occurs when you've dwelled on a frame for more than 15 seconds.